# ошибка $_GET

Tags: php, get

Есть файл , index.php

Если открыть в браузере `index.php?sex=boy`, должен загрузиться список с значением boy 
но выдает ошибку, пустая страница :( 
кто нить видит ошибку?

```
$db->query("select * from peoples where sex='.$_GET['sex'].'");
while($line=$db->get_row()){
    echo '<ul><li><a href="'.$line['url'].'"> '.$line['name'].'</a></li></ul>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from peoples where sex='".$_GET['sex']."'");
    while($line=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo '<ul><li><a href="'.$line['url'].'"> '.$line['name'].'</a></li></ul>'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Какой петросян поставил минус и за что. Отзовись убожество.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sex']); #так типо безопаснее
$db->query("select * from peoples where sex='$sex'");
```

Comment: пишет Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/h6952/data/www/factorname.ru/new/test.php on line 26

вот 26 строка $db->query("select * from peoples where sex='$sex'");

Comment: Пословица такая есть, (перевод дословный, но смысл не потерян), нет вины у того, кто не знает и спросил, а вот тот кто знает и не ответил, тот грешен (имеется ввиду познание чего либо) :)

Comment: @meravaz, грешен тот программист, кто с доступом к гуглу не прочитал ни одной книги по программированию. Истину говорю вам.

ЗЫ: У вас переменная $db не определена.

ЗЗЫ: @shurik +1 )

Comment: 1 - просто иногда хочется получить ответ от человека, 
2 - если в гугл лазить то все созданные вами форумы перестанут функционировать, сами подумайте :)
3 - это сайт hashcode тут дают конкретный ответ а не обсуждалку включают,  не хотите ответить/помочь проходите просто мимо.
4 - а тем кто ответил хотел наградить по у меня не хватает очков уважения. :(

Comment: @meravaz, форум не мной создан и тут очень много вопросов, ответы на которые можно получить _только_ от человека, потому что его либо сложно сформулировать, либо в гугле только китайский результат. И вообще он позиционируется как "форум программистов для программистов", а не "сайт с бесплатными уроками элементарных алгоритмов для самых маленьких". Почитайте хоть одну книгу, правда. Можно даже по php3.

Comment: @meravaz, а у вас ус отк... то есть, не определен объект класса для работы с БД.  
И вообще, пихать $_GET в БД необработанном виде опасно.

Answer (score 0):

Не пробовали так?

```
$sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sex']);  
$db->query("select * from peoples where sex='{$sex}'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше так:

```
$sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sex']);
$db->query("select * from peoples where sex='".$sex."'");
```

Если не получится, то вот так:

```
$db->query("select * from peoples where sex=\'".$sex."\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

А лучше всего, т.к. sex может быть только boy или girl,

```
if(isset($_GET['sex'])) $sex=$_GET['sex'];
if($sex=='boy'||$sex=='girl')
...("select * from `peoples` where `sex`='$sex'")
```

PS про синтаксис mysql не забываем.